# Checking for null in cells

Tags: vba, excel

Code:

```
    Sub Usuns()
Dim wiersz, licznik As Integer
wiersz = 0
licznik = 0
Do
licznik = licznik + 1
 If Range("B" & licznik).Value Is Null Then
  Range("B" & licznik).Select
  Selection.Delete
  wiersz = wiersz + 1
 Else
  wiersz = 0
 End If
 If wiersz = 50 Then
       Exit Do
 End If
Loop
End Sub
```

This line `If Range("B" & licznik).Value Is Null Then`
throws this error:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the value `Null` this way.

You should try:

```
If Range("B" & licznik).Value = ""
```

See [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/whats-equivalent-null-vba-t3106197.html) for a small discussion about `Null`.

Comment: Note that `Range("B" & licznik).Value = ""` will return `True` if the cell contains an empty string (i.e. `=""`). Does the OP want this? I don't know.

Comment: @Jean-François: thanks for this tip. Btw, your answer is far more thorough than mine +1!

Answer (score 1):

### #NULL!

I think you're looking to detect whether a cell contains the Excel error code `#NULL!`. To do this you need to use the [`CVErr` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251526%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
If Range("B" & licznik).Value = CVErr(xlErrNull)
```

### Empty cells

If, however, you want to test for empty (blank) cells, you'll want to use the [`IsEmpty` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
If IsEmpty(Range("B" & licznik).Value) Then
```

Note that this is the only way to strictly test for blank cells. Other tricks will not behave in the same way; for instance, `Range("B" & licznik).Value = ""` will return `True` if the cell contains an empty string (i.e. `=""`) whereas `IsEmpty` will return `False`. Depends what you want to do. Choose cautiously.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that `Range` needs to be in scope of its parent worksheet object.

So either:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("B" & licznik).Value
```

or

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
    'some code...

    .Range("B" & licznik).Value

    'some more code...
End With
```

Comment: if you don't specify it explicitly, Excel assumes you want to specify the current Sheet (this can be tricky but does not raise an error)